# Meaning of "running stationary radar down"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, meaning-in-context, vocabulary, sentence-meaning

I heard this in a true crime show. The whole quote goes like this: (He's a police officer btw)

> At approximately 10 pm, I was sitting here running stationary radar
> down towards the Circle K.

So what was he doing exactly? Was he operating his radar? Why towards that place? I have no idea what he means here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stationary radar is otherwise known as a police "speed trap" See [How Police Radar Works"](https://radartest.com/how-radar-works.asp):

> How Police Radar is Used
>
> Two types of radar are used—stationary and moving. Stationary radar must be used from a static site, typically a patrol car parked at roadside, sometimes a motorcycle. The most common type of stationary-mode radar is the hand-held model that looks like an oversized pistol.

Your sentence is parsed: I was sitting here running stationary radar *[down towards the Circle K.]*  where "down towards the Circle K." is an adverbial phrase modifying "running"

**down towards the Circle K.** = down (i.e. along) the road in the direction of the ranch that is called "the Circle K"

Comment: Thank you so much! It makes sense now.

Comment: Whilst "the Circle K" could be a ranch it's more likely to be one of a large [chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_K) of convenience stores and gas (fuel) stations.